# String Data into Column with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

[image: Image 1: In the image of the website from where i have extract data. same column]

[image: Image 2: Data which have been extract from the website but in one column (no space and column). I want change this data in the same format(table) as it looks in the image 1.]

Image 1: Website image from where i wanted to extract/**scrape** data.

Image 2: I have successfully **scraped** Data from the website but no what i wanted too. there need to be 13 columns(as in image 1) but all the data were been extracted one column (no space and column). I want change this data in the same format(table) as it looks in the image 1.

looking forward for your positive response.

**DATA IN EXCEL FILE**

follow the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iy63t4N_aBNNM6L2zFHuna5RN-spu-BR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: how did you extract it, what did you use? because without any delimiter it's not possible to do that with the data from the excel you have to change the way you get the data from the website.

Comment: @Boendal thanks for your kind response i have extracted this data with the help of third party software.

Comment: you should use python to extract the data if it's possible. Without any delimiter there is no way to extract the data you want.

Comment: i have extracted the data but not in way i wanted. you can see in the website imag, their are more then 10 columns. i was able to extract right data but rather then having 10+ columns all data were extracted in 1 columns (no space). Rows are fine. follow the links to see the data which i have extracted : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iy63t4N_aBNNM6L2zFHuna5RN-spu-BR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your time and response. This is what i get after running your code, see the result --> 
` ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A13', 'A14', 'A15'] Couldn't process: ['Column 1'] Process finished with exit code 0 `

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are delimiters but in your screenshot they weren't visible and I didn't bother to watch the excel file so sorry for that.

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("data.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# you have to name your columns by hand because not in the data (I put dummy value inside because lazy)
header = ['A'+str(i) for i in range(0,16)] 
print(header)

data = {}

for row_num in range(sh.nrows):
    row = sh.row_values(row_num)[0].split("\n") # The delimiter is '\n'
    if not len(row) == len(header): #To not have the single column1 value in the data
        print("Couldn't process: ", row)
        continue
    for index,column in enumerate(row):
        data[header[index]] = data.get(header[index],[]) + [column]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So the delimiter was '\n' you can split with that.

The column name you have to input yourself for me I named it A0 to A15 because lazy to write them down from the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your time and response. This is what i get after running your code, see the result -->

['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'A13', 'A14', 'A15']

Couldn't process:  ['Column 1']

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @Zeeshanhmm that is normal don't worry as you can see I print("Couldn't process: , row) for rows it couldn't process as debug. It should only print column1 because that is a row that doesn't contains data. The df is created correctly. This would only print another row if you have error in your data.